# How to check or monitoring if sitemap works on particular websites

Tags: xml, web, dreamweaver, sitemap

`sitemap.xml` file has been created on the Website.but my question how and where  can I Check if it  is successfully run or works  on a particula websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different search engines are different, but for Google, you can go to the Google Search Console to see crawling stats. You'll probably have to register your site and then submit your sitemap manually to get it going, but it'll show you which pages have been crawled, how many are being crawled per day, any errors with your sitemaps, etc.

Here's a link to Search Console:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Comment: thanks Andy for giving  some information..I only created the file and send it to the manager..I thought i would have a chance to view it while updating and maintaining the site

Answer (score 0):

Crowlet does exactly that (full disclosure: I am the maintainer). 
It is a lightweight CLI program checking all URLs from your sitemap.xml, and report if there is a response code or response time issue.

It is basically a one-liner, that can return a specific exit code based issues encountered, or be parsed as JSON (logstash, ...).

The project's here: https://github.com/Pixep/crowlet.

And an example to match what you were looking for:

```
# Return with code `150` if any page has a status != 200
docker run -it --rm aleravat/crowlet --non-200-error 150 https://foo.bar/sitemap.xml
```